# Controlling time-out of memcached when using it as a cache backend for Django's cached_db session setting

Tags: django, memcached

In a Django project when using `cached_db` type session caching:

1) How does one control the `time-out` of the cache backend? For instance, I want each session data object saved in memcached to have a `ttl` of 20 days. I moreover want this `ttl` to update on subsequent writes (if they happen).

2) Will memcached automatically scale to consume all RAM available in case there's a huge influx of session writes? Can I dictate the memory allocation? Moreover, are there any best-practices if there's a spike in data? When I see `/etc/memcached.conf`, there doesn't seem to be a lot of levers one can pull.

3) Once a ttl is successfully added to cached session objects, how does one about testing that it actually works?

Would be awesome to get an illustrative answer.

---

**Background:** I've traditionally relied on DB-based session caching, and only now have mulled shifting over to `cached_db`. Thus I'm somewhat green on the subject.

My current cache settings are as follows (set in `settings.py`):

```
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
            'LOCATION':'unix:/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The backend accepts a [`TIMEOUT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-TIMEOUT) setting. You can also specify a different timeout when [setting a particular cache entry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#basic-usage).
2. Memcached does not automatically scale. It accepts an [`-m` command line argument](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ConfiguringServer#commandline-arguments) at startup to define the maximum amount of memory it should use for its cache. This defaults to 64MB. You can also change this limit during operation with the command `cache_memlimit <limit in MB>`. I can't speak to what best practises are - think it is a case of determining what sort of load you get and whether you need more memory to avoid cache evictions due to lack of space.
3. Something like this:

   ```
   from django.core.cache import cache

   cache.set('test_key', 'test_value', timeout=10)   # Short timeout of 10 seconds
   # 10 seconds later
   cache.get('test_key')   # Should return None because the entry has expired
   ```

Comment: Regarding 3) I've already done testing of the sort you've surmised in `3`. How do I test that my session data is getting cached (and subsequently purged) correctly? When I peer into the `debug toolbar`, I get the sense that my session data is always routed from the `cache`; it doesn't matter if I set `TIMEOUT` to `60`. It should be a `cache miss` after 60 seconds in that scenario right? Very peculiar. Maybe I haven't configured it correctly.

Comment: @HassanBaig You could check the memcached stats between each operation and see if there was a set, get hit, or get miss. This will give you clarity what is going on in your cache.